# Changing value of variable "cookies"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a cookie clicker clone.

So when press the cookie I want the value of 'cookies' to add 1
(0 turns into 1, 1 turns into 2 and so on)

I tried with these codes but it didn't work

index.html:

```
<body>
    <center>
        <p id="cookie" style="font-size=72"></p>
        <p>
            <button onclick="cookieclick()" type="button">
                <img src="Chocochip_Cookie_512.png"  />
            </button
        </p>
    </center>
    <script src="cookies.js"></script>
</body>
```

cookies.js:

```
var cookies = 0;
document.getElementById("cookie").innerHTML = "Cookies:<br>" + cookies;
function cookieclick() {
    cookies + 1;
}
```

Can anyone point out what I did wrong?

Comment: Downvotes were likely unnecessary, they question may be simple but the OP explained what the problem was and posted the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

- You have to update the `innerHTML` when you click the element.
- You have to assign the value of `cookies + 1` back into `cookies`

**Code**

```
var cookies = 0;    
function cookieclick() {
  // This would work: cookies++;
  // This would also workd: cookies +=1;
  cookies = cookies + 1;
  document.getElementById("cookie").innerHTML = "Cookies:<br>" + cookies;
}
```

Comment: And also `font-size=72`, CSS doesn't work like this. And also the missing `>` in `</button`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 That's true, just not related to the question

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing the value back into the variable.

```
cookie = cookies + 1;
```

Comment: Plus, they are not rewriting the HTML when the p tag is clicked